# Python script to loop through multiple Excel files (same structure) and extract data

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I currently have code that looks like this: where a path is defined and I loop over all files in a directory that end with `.xlsx`.

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

path ="C:\\Users\\Adam\\Desktop\\Stock Trackers\\"

excel_file_list = os.listdir(path)

finalDf = pd.DataFrame()
for file in excel_file_list:
    if excel_files.endswith(".xlsx"):

        df = pd.read_excel(path+file,sheet_name="Main",usecols="A:D,R")
        df=df.dropna(how='all') #why is this not removing NaN, change first line to read all .xlsx in the folder
        df['Qty Received']=df['Total Received']
        df = df.drop('Total Received', axis=1)
        df['InvoicedValue'] = df['Price']*df['Qty Invoiced']
        df['ReceivedValue'] = df['Price']*df['Qty Received']
        df['DeltaQty']= df['Qty Received']-df['Qty Invoiced']
        df['DeltaValue']= df['ReceivedValue']-df['InvoicedValue']
        df.insert(loc=0, column='filename', value=filename)
        finalDf = pd.concat([df])

FinalFile=finalDf.to_excel(finalfile.xlsx)
```

So this code is currently not working as the "finalfile" (see last line) is not defined, so my first question is: can I output data to a file that doesn't exist but is then created in the process (I thought it would be auto-created if it didn't exist)?

That aside, I am not sure my code (especially the penultimate concat line) actually works. Essentially I just want to pull column data from each file in the directory and then stack it on top of each other. The files have the same structure.

Answer (score 0):

About the file being created during the process of dataframe.to_excel("file_name.xlsx"), YES, it'll create a new file and save on it. [Pandas save to Excel documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

About your script:

- Give a try to glob function. You can import it with `from glob import glob`. And use it to get a list of files from a folder that match a pattern. So you could use it as: `files = glob(FR"path\*.xlsx")` and the files variable now will have just .xlsx files from the folder. [Glob documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html).
- The idea of the for loop it's correct, but the last line of it is not. It should be: `finalDf = pd.concat([finalDf, df])` [Pandas concat documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)
- The last line of your code is not correctly too. The file name should be pass as a string. So: `FinalFile=finalDf.to_excel("finalfile.xlsx")`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. With regards to your first point, thanks for the suggestion - however, is it necessary to use glob? Can I not proceed with the method above? Just trying to understand. With regards to the second point, I am trying to understand how we can concat finalDf and df in the first instance when finalDf doesn't exist yet at this point? Finally, with regards to your third point, will the newly created file be created in the directory I am working in in Python?

Comment: @user20777937 About the first point, in my opinion the biggest difference between my recommendation and what you did is that with glob you already get the full path of the files, but your script should work fine. About the second point, you created the finalDf before the for loop, with finalDf = pd.DataFrame(), so, you can concat itself with the df. And about the last point, yes, it is going to create the final in the directory that you are working. To save in another location you should pass the full path+filename in the argument as: finalDf.to_excel(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\finalfile.xlsx")

Comment: The script works but the issue is that the line  df.insert(loc=0, column='filename', value=filename) inserts a column that is 400,000 rows long. How can I modify it so that each time the column is created it matches the length of the other columns for that particular file?

Comment: Change the insert line to: df['filename'] = filename. I think that's what you are looking for.

Comment: I did that but the same issue persists. I think it might be to do with the QtyReceived column as this seems to have zeros even in rows where there is no data.